# How to add controls to html document based on mouse position and jQuery UI Draggable?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am creating a form designer and have a toolbox that contains images of button, textbox etc.
The user will drag each of these controls to the form, so I am using jQuery `Draggable()` . After dropping somewhere in the form this control (or image) should return back to its place in toolbox then a real control should be inserted into the position that user dropped the control in the form.

This is what I did:

```
<div id="tools">
    <div id="draggables">
        <img class="tool" alt="Button" id="button" src="Data/Button.png" />
        <img class="tool" alt="TextBox" id="textBox" src="Data/TextBox.png" />
        <img class="tool" alt="RadioButton" id="radioButton" src="Data/RadioButton.png" />
        <img class="tool" alt="CheckBox" id="checkBox" src="Data/CheckBox.png" />
    </div>
    <img alt="Trash" id="trash" src="Data/trash.png" />
</div>
```

then:

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggables").children().draggable();
});
```

**The problem is:** what should I add to the end of `draggable()`(or anywhere else) to insert the **specified** control into the selected position in the form?

any better solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is example of realization [Shoping Cart](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart) on base of JQuery UI droppable.

This have similar behavour to your task: item after copy to cart return on it's place.

But you will need to solve problem with adding unique forms elements names when copy several form elements.